# How to share multiple files simultaneously in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Am new to flutter . I am using flutter_share package to share files. but now i want to share more than one file at a time. is this possible with flutter? I am using dio to download file and path_provider to get the filepath.
If anyone know please help me to solve this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share 
full example code https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart 
You can convert file to `Uint8List` then share with `Share.files` 
code snippet

```
Future<void> _shareMixed() async {
    try {
      final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
      final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
      final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

      await Share.files(
          'esys images',
          {
            'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
          },
          '*/*',
          text: 'My optional text.');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done. And it works perfectly on Android. But on iOS when I am using this, the text is used in Email App such as Gmail, as Subject, Body and within the body twice. Should there be another parameter to pass in this? On i OS WhatsApp the image is not shared at all?

Comment: @chunhunghan How can I share different text with each image?

Comment: This package doesn't support null safety!

Answer (score 0):

This function is easy work with gmail share and image file is also open. But problem with social media share like when 4 to 5 image share with whatsup share. Image list show like file image. Help about exact solution  and easy share with whatsup image.

Use below code :

```
Future<void> _shareMixed() async {
    try {
      final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/ic_back.svg');
      final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/ic_back.svg');
      final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/ic_back.svg');

      await Share.files(
          'esys images',
          {
            'back1.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'back2.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
            'back3.png': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
          },
          '*/*',
          text: 'My optional text.');

    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

[image]