# How do I share multi image on iOS and Android using Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, share

I would like to share multi image using the standard share dialog in ios and Android.

How can I create a "share" button for multi image using flutter.

I found some code like this for share an image

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.png', bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'image/png');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share multiple files simultaneously in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598206/how-to-share-multiple-files-simultaneously-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share 
To share multiple files or images with `Share.files`

code snippet

```
final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image1.png');
final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

await Share.files(
    'esys images',
    {
        'esys.png': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
        'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
    },
    '*/*',
    text: 'My optional text.');
```